# how to import twurl into python?

Tags: python, twitter, rubygems

I am trying the wrapper around twitter using ruby gem twurl, but I am not able to import into python using

```py
import twurl
```

I have the gem **twurl** installed already from ruby

Comment: Twurl is a ruby application, and is not available in Python. I would recommend finding an API library for Python.

Comment: I agree, but there are programs like [this]( https://pypi.org/project/rython/) which make it simple instead of forcing us to learn new library. So I wanted to hear about all such wrappers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is not supposed to be a lengthy answer, but since I am not yet allowed to give comments here we go:
there is a course from a professor of the Uni of Michigan who provides a twurl.py file for free which works just fine (no need to concern oneself with ruby):

https://www.py4e.com/materials

(go for the link "Individual Files" and there you will find it, ready for download)